# Getting JSON data with two results using jqPlot ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, jqplot

I'm fetching some data from my database. The result is `[["2011-05-10","1000"],["2011-05-16","5000"]]`, but it can't be rendered. I get an uncaught exception. `[object Object]` is the FireBug output. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
    var ret = null;
    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      url: url,
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(data) {
        ret = data;
      }
    });
    return ret;
  };

  var jsonurl = "jsondata.php";

  var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
    title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    dataRendererOptions: {
      unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
    },axes: {
          xaxis: {
              renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
              min:'January 1, 2011',
              max: 'December 30, 2011',
              tickOptions:{formatString:'%B'}
          },
          yaxis: {
          min: 0,
          tickInterval: 1
          }
      },
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you already try: JSON.parse(data)

Comment: i manage to fetch the data and render it. but the line connector is not showing.

Comment: One obvious thing is that you have strings instead of numbers: `["2011-05-10","1000"]` the 1000 is a string.

Comment: the result in data is still the json, I'm sure if you log it, it would be like {[[.. ],[...]]} You first need to take the array out of the json before you can return it to jqplot

Comment: My previous comment doesn't make sense, sorry for that... Can you log the received data in the ajaxDataRenderer? It should be an object literal or json like, not an array. You need to do that conversion yourself.

Comment: sorry. i manage to get the json data having [[["2011-05-10",1000],["2011-05-16",5000]]] outpu. i change the datatype of "1000" so that it will be an int. anyway thanks.. this question is already solved.